# Python - Assigning attributes to a class instance using a for loop and a list

Tags: python, data-structures

Hi folks I am experimenting with Python (I found pygame.org and wanted to play around) and I am trying to read some settings from a configuration file. I want to be able to change stats on the fly. (So if I wanted to change how hard a fighter hits or how fast a wizard runs then I'd be able to do that.) I was hoping to be able to read from a list and create an attribute for each instance in the list basically this:

```
for stat in Character.stats:
    self.stat = parser.get(self.char_class, stat)
```

What ends up happening is there is an object with an attribute names 'stat' that contains the last value assigned. What I would LIKE to happen is to have an attribute created for each item in the list, and then get assigned the related value from the config file.

here is more code for context:

```
class Character(object):

    stats = ["level_mod", 
            "power",
            "speed",
            "hit",
            "evade",
            "magic",
            "stamina",
            "magic_defense",
            "intelligence"]

    def __init__(self, name, rpg_id):
        self.name = name
        self.rpg_id = rpg_id
        self.__setStats()

    def __setStats(self):
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.read('char_config.cfg')
        for stat in Character.stats:
            self.stat = parser.get(self.char_class, stat)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you Krzysztof Rosiński I used setattr() and it worked a treat.

I will be creating a new 'stats' class as well because I liked what Raydel Miranda said. 

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, setattr:

```
for stat in Character.stats:
    setattr(self, stat, parser.get(self.char_class, stat))
```

Or manually access **dict**

```
for stat in Character.stats:
    self.__dict__[stat] = parser.get(self.char_class, stat))
```

Comment: Directly accessing `__dict__`  will bypass any existing descriptor (property etc).

Answer (score 0):

You want `setattr(obj, attrname, value)`

Answer (score 0):

You better re-design that part of the game by adding a `Stats` class.

```
class Stats:

    STATS = ["level_mod", 
            "power",
            "speed",
            "hit",
            "evade",
            "magic",
            "stamina",
            "magic_defense",
            "intelligence"]


    def __init__(self, conf_file=None):
        self.__stats = {}
        if conf_file is not None:
            self.loads_stats_from_file(conf_file)

    def load_stats_from_file(self, conf_file):
        """
        Here add the pairs <stat_name>:<value> 
        to the self.__stats dict. For that just parse the config
        file like before.
        """
        pass

    def get_stat(self, stat_name):
        return self.__stats[stat_name]

    def set_stat(self, stat_name, value):
        self.__stats[stat_name] = value
```

Then you can add a `Stats` instance to your `Character`.

```
class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, name, rpg_id):

        self.stats = Stats("char_config.cfg")
        self.name = name
        self.rpg_id = rpg_id
```

This way you improve usability and decouple the `Stats` and `Character` logics. And besides, your problem is reduced from *"Adding attributes to an object"* to *"Adding items to a dictionary"*.